# How to pronounce " bored " before "watching"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, spoken-english, reading, ipa

I am wondering how to pronounce "you may have gotten bored watching that". I have little understanding about if I should pronounce the 'd' in  /bɔrd/ or just /bɔr/ before the word 'watching'.

Comment: As a native AmE speaker, I never skip the d in bored, regardless what comes afterward.

Comment: Why do you think the final 'd' of a past participle might be omitted?

Comment: I read about 'final stop between consonants' ....   "When a stop is followed by another consonant, do not release the stop"....so that's the reason I thought in that way.I read that 'd' is a voice consonant. Does It only applies for unvoiced consonants? . Let me know if I'm in a mistake.Thanks for all replies.

Comment: @gabriel "do not release" doesn't mean "make it silent". In a normal released /d/ sound you move your tongue above your teeth and then move it back a little so a breath of air goes out. (You notate that small puff of air as /ᵊ/) When /d/ is before another consonant, we don't move the tongue back to get /ᵊ/ and then go do the consonant, we just immediately go to the consonant. Not */bɔɹ.dᵊ.wɑ.t͡ʃɪŋ/ but /bɔɹd.wɑ.t͡ʃɪŋ/ or /bɔɹ.dwɑ.t͡ʃɪŋ/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people usually say:

> /bɔɹd/

as the general american prounciation in the wiktionary [here](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/bored)

I do not see any reason to pronounce it without the "d" at the end, no matter the use in a sentence.